# Do sitemaps need to cover the entire site?

Tags: seo, sitemap

Do sitemaps need to cover the entire site?

If I have a sitemap link to all the most important views on the site, I should expect that all the first-child pages on that site should get crawled without explicitly defining them right?

Answer (score 0):

You may expect all URLs which are linked to by pages on your sitemap to be [crawled](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70897#E), still I would advise on including them in the sitemap, as it [provides meta-data](http://www.sitemaps.org/index.html). 
Keep in mind that the [position of a page in your sitemap doesn't matter](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_url_position). If you have lots of pages and want to keep things organized for yourself, you can [split the map into several files](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index). Otherwise, it's probably wisest to let the crawler figure out which pages are more important using the [`priority`](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#prioritydef) attribute.